# Win32 equivalent of .NET's System.Diagnostics.Process.Exited event?

Tags: .net, winapi, process, signals

In .NET, you can subscribe to [the `Exited` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) on a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object and get asynchronous notification when the process exits.  This is really convenient for me.

Is there any equivalent in straight Win32 using signals or something?  The closest thing I an imagine is spawning a thread that does nothing but `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle with infinite timeout, and then call a callback.

Comment: That question is about system-wide monitoring.  I only care about processes that I've spawned myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a thread that calls WaitForSingleObject() on the process handle will work.  But that's wasteful, you can get the operating system to do that for you with [RegisterWaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The exact same function that the .NET Process class uses to raise the Exited event.

Exact same kind of constraints in what you can do in the callback, it runs on an arbitrary threadpool thread so you have to properly interlock where necessary to keep your code thread-safe.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am getting system error code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5) when calling WaitForSingle(Multiple)Object(s). Any idea why ? I am opening the process successfully and getting a valid handle to it

Comment: You may get that if you are trying to wait on processes belonging to another user, or running under your user, but as an admin.

Comment: I created a sample for using RegisterWaitForSingleObject() to receive a callback: see http://www.ikriv.com/blog/?p=1431

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of `CreateProcess` is `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct which contains `hProcess` handle, you can use this handle with `WaitForSingleObject`